# Ребят, можете объяснить что от меня хотят?

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм

Делаю такой лабораторные, 4 за вечер так сказать и тут такое задание :"Дана последовательность, содержащая от 2 до 30 слов, в каждом из которых от 2 до 10 строчных
русских букв, между соседними словами - не менее одного пробела, за последним словом -
точка. Напечатать все слова последовательности, которые отличаются от последнего слова, предварительно
превратив каждое из них по следующему правилу: удалить из слова все предыдущие вхождения
последней буквы."
Можете объяснить что нужно в этом задании сделать?

Comment: Странно, что человек обращается к посторонним людям, вместо преподавателю для разъяснения

Comment: Та вы этого препода не знаете просто. Он перед тем как объяснит ещё и задолбает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В таких случаях лучше просить пояснить преподавателя, описание ниже только моё мнение на основе прочитанного. Преподаватель вполне мог иметь ввиду что-то другое.

На вход подается последовательность из слов, от 2 до 30, разделенных пробелами (не обязательно одним) и заканчивается точкой:

`"мама мыла раму когда     рама    мыла здесь было слово     еще слова   рама."`

Нужно взять все слова, которые отличаются от последнего слова, в данном случае "рама": `мама мыла раму когда мыла здесь было слово еще слова`. А дальше в каждом слове удалить буквы, которые равны последней, кроме самой последней.

Если это слово "мама" и последняя буква "а", то удаляем так "мма". Если это молоко, то удаляем все буквы "о", кроме самой последней "млко". По итогу должно получится так: `"мма мыла раму когда мыла здесь было слво ще слова"`.

Comment: Спасибо! Препода спрашивать не вариант(не простой человек)

Answer (score 1):

ну вы не думайте о коде, просто попробуйте решить на бумаге задачу в лоб:

алгоритм же в принципе простой:

1. разделить строку на слова используя метод `split()`
2. пройти последовательно от первого слова до предпоследнего и запоминать последнюю букву слова в некоторый список
3. если слово отличается от последнего слова в списке, то удалить у него все буквы, которые присутствуют в собираемом списке,

для этого можно пройтись по анализируемому слову как по списку букв и проверять, присутствуют ли буквы в списке и из букв, которые в списке не присутствуют собрать новое слово

для этого нужно только `for` и `not in`

Comment: та я не то что-бы о коде думал, я не понимал задачу( препод просто взял русскую задачу на pascal и перевёл через гугл транслейт на украинский, и такой:"разбирайтесь"). Но спасибо за алгоритм